# Chat + Map = NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzUV

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I set up chat on firebase and it worked. But when i'm adding the `map`, chat stopped work.

When i'm trying open chat in the app i get the error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzUV
```

*my dependencies:*

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your `build.gradle` file and `Rebuild` project.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1'
```

Comment: What is it showing the same error ? Please post new *Logcat*.

Comment: Thanks. but, your version is too old, i've set 10.0.1 and it's working.

Comment: @WladimirRudnicky Accept and upvote the answer i have made correction to that.